# Determine all bounded holomorphic functions f on $\mathbb{C}$ \ V where V is a discrete subset of C

Tags: complex-analysis

for the above question, does it necessarily mean that f is a meromorphic function, where by I can assume that the excluded discrete points (countably infinite) are actually the poles to f?

Hmm, any idea on how should I solve the question?

Thanks!

Comment: My crystal ball says you've recently learned theorems about the structure of holomorphic functions near isolated singularities, and particularly, a theorem about bounded holomorphic functions near isolated singularities...?

Comment: Hi @Andrew, thanks for your tip! Does it mean that f has removable singularities at z1,...,zk,....? but how do I check that the limit exists hmm!

Comment: What's your definition of "removable singularity"? :)

Comment: hmm, suppose z0 is a removable singularity of f. Means f is analytic/holomorphic in the Disk excluding the point z0?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: It will probably help to review the definitions of an [isolated singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_singularity) and a [removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity).